# Why does Ruby's IPAddr#family method return 2 when called on an IPv4 address, and 10 when called on an IPv6?

Tags: ruby

Using IPAddr from stdlib:

```
IPAddr.new('192.168.0.1').family
=> 2

IPAddr.new('1a03:a240:0100:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000').family
=> 10
```

So I'm guessing that 2 represents IPv4, and 10 represents IPv6. Why 2 and 10? Why not 4 and 6?

It makes no sense to use 2 and 10, as it implies that IPv4 is binary, and that IPv6 is base 10, when in fact they're both binary (under the hood), and the human-readable form of IPv4 is base 10 whereas for IPv6 it's hex...

Is there some deeper logic that I don't know about?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the leap from the family values to base 2/base 10. You sure it's not just a magic number, kind of like http://www.iana.org/assignments/address-family-numbers/address-family-numbers.xhtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This numbers are constants defined in `Socket` module.
IPv4 address family is `Socket::AF_INET`, IPv6 is `Socket::AF_INET6`

What suprised me, on my Ruby (2.0) the number for AF_INET6 is different than yours:

```
[9] pry(main)> IPAddr.new('1a03:a240:0100:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000').family
=> 30
[10] pry(main)> Socket::AF_INET6
=> 30
[11] pry(main)> Socket::AF_INET
=> 2
```

So it is better not to use the number themselves, but the constants names.

Comment: The numbers are different on the different platform, I use Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks! You've also highlighted a really important point! I was going to switch on the numeric value returned by family, but I don't think I'll be doing that now.

Answer (score 2):

These are the POSIX socket address families, as defined in sys/socket.h (see [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) for example). This includes all sorts of things like IPX, appletalk, unix domain sockets etc. They are just numbered sequentially, hence IPv6 having a larger number

While it might seem natural to give IPv4 the identifier 4 and IPv6 the identifier 6, these are probably the only two with such obvious mappings, and originally IPv4 was just IP

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a decisions that ruby made. It is the same value used for a macro in [linux's code base](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/socket.h#L144). Keeping the two constants in sync is quite important I believe. Also I think that constants were gradually added to the address family list and thus no one actually expected `AF_INET6` by the time the value of `AF_INET` was chosen. And then it was to late to change the value of `AF_INET`(and at the same time 6 was already occupied).

Comment: Thanks! I can get on with my work now that this is sorted out

Answer (score 1):

They are value of `Socket::AF_INET` and `Socket::AF_INET6`:

```
>> Socket::AF_INET
=> 2
>> Socket::AF_INET6
=> 10
```

and they come from socket-related header file. For example, in my ubuntu box:

```
$ grep PF_INET */*/*.h
i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:#define    PF_INET         2       /* IP protocol family.  */
i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:#define    PF_INET6        10      /* IP version 6.  */
i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:#define    AF_INET         PF_INET
i386-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h:#define    AF_INET6        PF_INET6
```